# При использовании setFont в paintComponent при старте программы 1 - 1.5 секунды неперерисованное окно

Tags: java, graphics

Есть панель, которая на форме в методе paintComponent я рисую строку. Но при запуске из Netbeans, да и просто jar файла где-то одна-полторы секунды отображается как бы неперерисованное окно.

```
 public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            Font textFont = new Font( "SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 20 );        
            String text = "This is text for testing";
            g.setFont( textFont );              
            g.drawString( text, 10, 100 );
            Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D) g; 
        }            
    }
```

но если убрать g.setFont( textFont ); то всё будет очень быстро работать и оставить вот так:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            Font textFont = new Font( "SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 20 );        
            String text = "This is text for testing";
            g.drawString( text, 10, 100 );
            Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D) g; 
        }            
    }
```

если же я после `Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D) g;` добавлю

```
FontRenderContext context = g2.getFontRenderContext();
Rectangle2D textBounds = textFont.getStringBounds( text, context );
```

то будет запускать еще чуть дольше, опять же с неперерисованным окном

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задержка действительно из-за setFont, не знаю получится ли от нее избавится. Я не спец по GUI, но могу сказать, что регулярное создание обьекта Font, String, в потоке отрисовки - не очень удачное решение. Вот список того, что вы могли бы попробовать:

1. что вы можете сделать, это вынести их обявление за пределы цикла (если это возможно конечно);
2. попробуйте сделать setFont сразу после создания компоненты (до первой прорисовки);
3. используя метрики шрифта, найти регион, который будет изменятся, и обновлять только его (и сетфонт применять только для этого объекта, если возможно конечно);
4. нарисовать ваш текст в отдельный буфер, а его рисовать на вашу компоненту (читать на тему двойной буферизации);
5. можно еще попробовать дорисовывать текст в отдельном потоке (чтоб не задерживать прорисовку самого окна):

```
    public void paintComponent ( final Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent ( g ) ;

Runnable writer = new Runnable()
        {
            @ Override
            public void run ()
            {
                Font textFont = new Font ( "SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 20 ) ;
                String text = "This is text for testing" ;
                g.setFont ( textFont );
                g.drawString ( text, 10, 100 ) ;
            }
        };

new Thread (writer).start ();
    }
```

Ну, и стоит заметить, что впервые вижу, чтоб переопределяли метод paintComponent вместо paint.

**UP:** если для вас это критично, можно просто сделать "флеш-скрин" - отображение картинки вместо основного окна пока оно не отрисуется :)

Comment: Вот еще линк нашел на официальном сайте: [Painting in AWT and Swing][1].

[1]: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html

Comment: 5 - ни в коем случае не делайте этого. Очень опасно выполнять операции с GUI из другого потока. Зато имеет смысл не создавать шрифт каждый раз заново.